# how to apply inner join in entityframework LINQ method syntax?

Tags: entity-framework-4, inner-join

How to apply this query in entity framework method syntax

```
select company_id, country_id from companies, departments where companies.company_id == departments.company_id and department.departmentId = 10;
```

So far, I have:

```
var company = context.companies
    .Where(com => com.Departments
        .Contains(context.departments
            .Where(dep => dep.department_id==_user.Department)
            .FirstOrDefault()
        )
    )
    .Select(com => new { com.company_id, com.Country })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using method based syntax, this could be as simple as;

```
var company = context.Companies
    .Where(x => x.Departments
        .Any(x => x.department_id == _user.Department)
    )
    .Select(x => new { x.company_id, x.Country });
```

This assumes your tables are set up with foreign keys giving each `Company` a list of `Department` objects. It very much depends on your data structure.

Comment: I edited the query because `contains` method does not take lambda expression but it takes object, anyway, can't we do the same query using the `join` method?

Comment: Sorry, `Contains` should have been `Any`

Comment: Why do you need to use `Join`?

Comment: just because I want to know how to do the same thing in different ways

Comment: This is the same thing in a different way, you're talking about doing the same thing in the same way :)